# vue test utils TypeError: Cannot destructure property `config` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: vue-test-utils

I'm doing just simple unit test with vue test utils.
but It's not working.
I've no clue....
help me

I installed this things.....

```
> $ npm i -D jest @vue/test-utils vue-jest jest-serializer-vue babel-jest babel-core@bridge

> $ npm i -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

I made *jest.config.js* file

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'vue',
    'js'
  ],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },

  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules',
    '<rootDir>/dist'
  ],

  testURL: 'http://localhost',

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$' : 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$' : 'babel-jest'
  }
}
```

and tests/Parent.test.js

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Parent from './Parent.vue'

test('Mount', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Parent)
  expect(wrapper.html()).toBe('')
})
```

but npm run test:unit error like this

```
 FAIL  tests/Parent.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot destructure property `config` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

      at Object.getCacheKey (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/index.js:10:5)
      at ScriptTransformer._getCacheKey (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:280:41)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:351:27)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:588:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:758:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:815:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.512 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Answer (score 18):

The package is moving away from *semantic versioning* to support a variety of Vue versions (2.x, 3.x) and Jest versions (26.x, 27.x). So, if you're using [Vue 3.x](https://v3.vuejs.org) and [Jest 27.x](https://jestjs.io), you need to install [vue3-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-jest), not [vue-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-jest).

```sh
npm i vue3-jest -D

# or

yarn add vue3-jest --dev
```

Then, update your `jest.config.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['vue', 'js', 'json', 'jsx'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue3-jest',
    '^.+\\js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
}
```

By the time of writing this answer, the package naming & versioning was like so:

[image]

You can read more about the new naming & versioning strategy [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/355).

Answer (score 11):

If you're using version 27 of jest, try downgrading to version 26. Make sure to downgrade babel-jest and ts-jest as well to version 26. I was getting the following error and that did it for me:

> Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'undefined' as it is
> undefined.

Comment: This was a nice clue, for me, I was using Jest 27,  but I needed to update it's companion `babel-jest` to 27 as well, since it was still at 24.  After I updated it started working.

Comment: @jfunk glad it helped

Comment: I have "babel-jest": "^27.0.6", "jest": "^27.0.6", "ts-jest": "^27.0.4", but still it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me thanks. Downgrading to "ts-jest": "26.5.6", "jest": "^26.6.3"

Comment: Great. Thanks, @AndrewBogdanov. downgraded and worked for me

Answer (score 9):

Was facing same issues trying to make Vue3, Jest and Typescript working tohgether.
This how i managed to make it work. Its a matter off aligning the planets with dependencies.

- First i suggest to clean package.json from any jest mentionning dependency (specialy if like me you spend few days trying to put and remove dependencies while performing a Rain dance holding a horseshoe).
- add to package.json
  `"devDependencies": {  "@babel/core": "^7.14.5", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7", "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0", "typescript": "^4.3.5", "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.9", "jest": "^26.5.6", "ts-jest": "^26.5.6", "babel-jest": "^26.5.6", "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-alpha.10", "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "5.0.0-beta.2" }` 
  (make sure that this depencies have the same version: jest, ts-jest and babel-jest)
- still in package.json add script `"scripts": { "test": "jest" },`
- npm i
- npm run test

And for me its now working. Hope it can help somebody else.

Answer (score 4):

If you upgraded Jest to 27.x.x, you will get this error and maybe other issues depending on your setup.
I had issues after upgrading to Jest 27 with my Vue3/TS/Jest setup.

1. Upgrade all jest related packages. I had to upgrade jest, jest-junit, ts-jest packages
2. Add the proper vue-jest. Chances are you will have to remove existing vue-jest package and install the correct package. I had to use @vue/vue3-jest. Use the below table to choose the correct package

[image]

Or read here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest

3. Fix jest configuration

   transform: {
   "^.+\.js$": "babel-jest",
   ".*\.(vue)$": "@vue/vue3-jest"
   }

For reference, here's my devDependencies.

[image]

Comment: Editing the `transform` in `jest.config.js` to use `@vue/vue3-jest` was the key to me. The version table was also very useful to confirm the versions I have installed, and to make me realize that from `vue-jest` and `@vue/vue*-jest` packages only one is needed at a time.