# How do I use Vue3 with vue-jest?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-jest

I have the following dependency...

```
"vue-jest": "latest",
```

But when I run `npm install` I get...

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: vue@3.1.4
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   vue@"latest" from the root project
npm WARN   7 more (@headlessui/vue, @heroicons/vue, @vue/compiler-sfc, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"^2.x" from vue-jest@3.0.7
npm WARN node_modules/vue-jest
npm WARN   dev vue-jest@"latest" from the root project
```

I looked at the code and I see a lib called [vue3-jest](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/tree/master/packages/vue3-jest) but that isn't available in npm...

What is the proper way to get the version of vue-jest that uses vue3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since `jest` v27,use vue3-jest instead.

```
npm i vue3-jest
```

[feat: support jest v27 in vue3-jest #343](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/pull/343)

Comment: the problem it is still an alpha version

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what [Vue Test Utils for Vue3 installation guide](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#usage), you should use  `vue-jest` v5 that is still in alpha because it's the one that supports Vue 3.

The `latest` version is `3.0.7`. But the version you need is `5.0.0-alpha.10`. It exists in the `next` channel so you should be able to install it using:

```
npm i vue-jest@next
```

You can check all `vue-jest` versions here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-jest in the Versions tab

Answer (score 0):

To fix this use the latest @vue/vue3-jest package.
NOT vue3-jest.

Read more here [vue test utils TypeError: Cannot destructure property `config` of 'undefined' or 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065635/vue-test-utils-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-config-of-undefined-or/70764540#70764540)